# No borders around buttons in dark themes in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, 17.04, customization, colors, borders

I have a problem with dark themes in Lubuntu 17.04. When I choose widget with dark colors (for example Elementary Dark), than in some applications I don't see borders around buttons, checkboxes and so on. Look at screenshots, where you can see problems in "LightDM GTK+ Greeter settings" window:

here I chose Lubuntu-default widget and everything is normal:
[light_widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNUoY.png)

and here I chose Elementary-Dark widget and there are no borders:
[dark_widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxE3R.png)

The same thing happens even when I choose standard widget Lubuntu-dark-panel. Can you help me to make Lubuntu draw borders in dark themes?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that the theme is not compatible with this version of GTK+. Lubuntu has versions 2.24 and 3.22.

I googled "dark theme gtk 3.22", and found that Adapta works fine.